# What is the order of the product of two elements of a group that has order $pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was asked this group theory question on my final exam for abstract algebra:

"Let $G$ be a group of order $pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. Suppose $a$ and $b$ are elements of $G$ with orders $p$ and $q$ respectively. Prove or disprove that $G$ must be abelian."

Can I say that $|ab|=\operatorname{lcm}(p,q)$, or does the group need to be abelian for that to hold? Can somebody provide hints or suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: The result is false as stated. $S_3$ is a group of order $pq$, $p=2$, $q=3$, which has elements of orders $p$ and $q$, but is not abelian. Are you neglecting to mention some hypothesis? Maybe that $a$ and $b$ commute?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin This is a great counter example, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

*Any* group of order $pq$, abelian or otherwise, has elements of order $p$ and $q$.

Why? [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) states that for $G$ a finite group, and $p$ a prime with $p \mid |G|$, then $G$ must have an element of order $p$.

It immediately follows that any group of order $pq$ has an element of order $p$ and an element of order $q$.

Comment: I edited the post to say "prove or disprove", since the result was false to begin with. Thank you for your input, it was insightful and helpful.

Comment: @AsherArmstrong Ah I see, thanks. I'll amend the question a little bit to match that. If you found the answer helpful and adequately answers your question, please accept it by clicking the checkmark :)